# Excel - absolute value no matter value was input into a cell

Tags: excel, absolute

I would like to absolute a total sum of value regardless of negative was keyed into the cell.

```
=SUM(ABS(C14:OFFSET(C18, -1, 0)))
```

Or Is there any ways I could do it to force only positive number to be entered in the workbook?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You could use `SUMIF`, to sum all potitive numbers, sum all negative numbers and then substract positive - negative, so the negative ones will become  positive.

If your range of numbers is for example A1:A100 use:

```
=SUMIF(A1:A100,">=0") - SUMIF(A1:A100,"<0")
```

**EDIT:** If you only want to sum positive numbers (and discard negative ones) just use the first part of the formula:

```
=SUMIF(A1:A100,">0")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ABS(C14:INDEX(C:C,ROW(C18)-1)))
```

Note: I used the Non-Volatile INDEX, instead of the Volatile OFFSET.